# Is a STL vector pf pointers to vectors my best option?

Tags: vector, stl

I currently have a ton of vectors all set to have 1200 items, which is overkill, but could be used. So I don't have to recode a lot of stuff, what is the best way to create and iterate through a list of these vectors and resize them all as needed? (they all are equal in size)

One of my options is to create a pointer (after the fact) to each vector, and then create a vector of these pointers which can be iterated to resize.  Another option is to create the vectors in the first place as pointers instead of objects. This seems like it would be a lot of work, and I currently have a lot of code where I use the vector objects.

Are there other options?

Fred E.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `std::vector` is just a wrapper around a raw data pointer. The vector itself stores data in the heap. So you can store vectors in a vector as objects, or you can store pointers to them.

The easiest way is to store vectors in a vector as objects, but you must carefully monitor how you pass this outer vector into functions. You should always pass it by reference or pass a pointer to it, so as not to trigger copying all nested vectors. On the other hand, such a vector will automatically and correctly remove nested vectors when its destructor fires.

The vector of pointers to vectors has its advantages and disadvantages. On the one hand, when a function is called inaccurately with this vector as a parameter, only pointers will be copied. On the other hand, accessing vectors through a pointer affects performance. In addition, when storing pointers to vectors, you must take care to delete them yourself.

If your vectors are created and deleted elsewhere and you only need to iterate through them and modify them in your code, then obviously the vector of pointers to vectors is your best choice.